# Visual Studio 2013 crashes when loading project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, crash, project

Some time ago I started developing with Visual Studio 2013 Professional and everything worked well. But a few weeks ago I upgraded to the Ultimate version. But since then Visual Studio crashes when I load a project. VS just starts up normally, I can see the menu and log in and stuff like that. But when I open a project it crashes everytime. I tried to repair it VS in the control panel, but still the same problem... Then I reinstalled it but when loading a solution it crashed again. Now I downgraded to Professional again, but now even Professional crashes.

I have been searching on google for a long time to solve this problem. I tried to reconfigure the debugger, even reinstalled it, but no effect. A lot of forums say you have to delete the .suo file in the project, but even that doesn't work...

Is there a solution for this?

---

**UPDATE**

When Visual Studio crashes I get this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnSid.png

My ActivityLog.xml is on OneDrive: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B3519F287A9CD3FC!2830&authkey=!AIUDHo1bCZan4Fk&ithint=file%2cxml

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed? Try disabling them before trouble shooting.

Comment: Yes I had, I disabled them and tried everything all over again, but it still crashes...

Comment: 1) Did you try running as administrator? 2) What is in the event log?

Comment: Yes I tried running as administrator but it crashed again while loading a project.

In the event log I get an application error with the EventData details:
devenv.exe 
   12.0.30501.0 
   5361f453 
   KERNELBASE.dll 
   6.3.9600.17415 
   54504ade 
   e0434352 
   00014598 
   96c 
   01d03623de0e95f8 
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe 
   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll 
   39bcda99-a217-11e4-8297-20256418dfca

Comment: I tried to run it in safe mode, and in safe mode it is working, but I can't use the extensions anymore in the Visual Studio. Does anybody know something to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already received the answer from the *MSDN* forum. And it was caused by the *Web Essentials* extension tool. And apparently with the *Visual Studio Update 4* everything seems to be fixed. The extension tool was causing the error, and that error is fixed in the update.

---

Thanks for the support everyone!